# Can't connect to access point (systemd-networkd), maybe DNS not set for wlan1

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, systemd

I'm trying to create an access point with my raspberry-pi 2B. There are no onbord wifi so I'm using 2 dongle.
Interface wlan0 is connected to my phone hotspot to be able to ssh.
Interface wlan1 is an alfa network dongle which I want to be my wifi access point.

I followed this guide : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way

My AP shows up in the list of wifi routers but when I try to connect, it fails when trying to obtain an IP adress then disconnects and tries to reconnect again and again.

Here is the result of resolvectl status :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ resolvectl status
Global
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 4 (wlan1)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes

Link 3 (wlan0)
      Current Scopes: DNS mDNS/IPv4
DefaultRoute setting: yes
       LLMNR setting: no
MulticastDNS setting: yes
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.43.1
         DNS Servers: 192.168.43.1

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
  DNSOverTLS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: allow-downgrade
    DNSSEC supported: yes
```

There are no DNS server setup for wlan1, could that be my problem ?

/etc/systemd/resolved.conf is default

/etc/systemd/network/08-wifi.network :

```
[Match]
Name=wl*

[Network]
## Uncomment only one option block
# Option: using a DHCP server and multicast DNS
LLMNR=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
MulticastDNS=yes
DHCP=ipv4

# Option: using link-local ip addresses and multicast DNS
#LLMNR=no
#LinkLocalAddressing=yes
#MulticastDNS=yes

# Option: using static ip address and multicast DNS
# (example, use your settings)
#Address=192.168.50.61/24
#Gateway=192.168.50.1
#DNS=84.200.69.80 1.1.1.1
#MulticastDNS=yes
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-wlan1.conf :

```
country=FR
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="RPiNet"
    mode=2
    frequency=2437
    key_mgmt=NONE   # uncomment this for an open hotspot
```